# Hey everyone! Need some assistance with a VB.Net exercise

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to complete this exercise:

> Modify the btnDisplay_Click procedure so that it uses two  functions named GetGrade101 and GetGrade201 to get the appropriate grade; the procedure  should then display the grade in the lblGrade control. Change the two independent Sub  procedures to functions that return the appropriate grade to the statements that invoke them  in the btnDisplay_Click procedure. Each function should contain a parameter that accepts  the total points passed to it.

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
    Dim intPoints As Integer
    Dim Grade As String
    Dim GGrade As String


    ' Independent Sub procedures.
    Private Function GetGrade101(ByVal intPoints As Integer) As String

        Select Case intPoints
            Case Is >= "90"
                Grade = "A"
            Case Is >= "80"
                Grade = "B"
            Case Else
                Grade = "F"

        End Select
        Return Grade
    End Function
    Private Function GetGrade102(ByVal intPoints As Integer) As String
        Select Case intPoints
            Case Is >= "75"
                Grade = "P"
            Case Else
                Grade = "F"

        End Select
        Return intPoints
    End Function

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        ' Calls independent Sub procedures to display a grade.



        If radHis101.Checked Then

            lblGrade.Text = GetGrade101(intPoints)

        Else
            lblGrade.Text = GetGrade102(intPoints)

        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPoints_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPoints.Enter
        txtPoints.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearGrade(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPoints.TextChanged, radHis101.CheckedChanged, radHis201.CheckedChanged
        lblGrade.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPoints_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPoints.KeyPress
        ' Accept only numbers and the Backspace key

        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this exercise or your code?

Comment: I wanted to try and get a letter grade to appear in the lblgarde control based on which radbutton i select. I keep getting a 0 or just an f every time

Comment: 90 is not the same thing as "90".  GetGrade102 returns intPoints?  Terrible title for a question.

Comment: Basically when I click the buttondisplay is should show me a letter grade based on the radbutton I picked while converting the number grade put in the text points text box to a letter grade to display in lblgrade control

Comment: Remove ASAP the line _Option Strict Off_  (or change to On) then look  and resolve the errors displayed. I don't really understand why on earth they still teach this thing

Comment: Thank You I will

Comment: You're passing `intPoints` to the functions, but never assigned a value to it...so the the current value in that variable is 0 (ZERO).  Do you have a TextBox, maybe, on the form where the user is supposed to enter the points?

Comment: Yes I do. The user is suppose to enter points into txtPoints

Answer (score 1):

In your two functions `GetGrade1010` and `GetGrade201`, it looks like you're treating the integer value `intpoints` as strings instead of integers.

Change your `SELECT` statements to be similar to this:

```
     Select Case intPoints
            Case Is >= 90    'Notice that there are no quotes around 90, etc.
                Grade = "A"
            Case Is >= 80
                Grade = "B"
            Case Else
                Grade = "F"
```

Also, I notice an error.  One of your functions (`GetGrade102` (shouldn't that be `GetGrade201`?)) is not returning the grade you're calculating.  Change "`Return intPoints`" to "`Return Grade`".

Comment: Doing this was a huge help. Only problem is now it only displays the letter f no

Answer (score 0):

> Only problem is now it only displays the letter f

You're passing `intPoints` to the functions, but never assigned a value to it...so the the current value in that variable is 0 (ZERO). Do you have a TextBox, maybe, on the form where the user is supposed to enter the points?

> Yes I do. The user is suppose to enter points into txtPoints

So you need to pull the value out of `txtPoints` and pass that to your grading function.  The TextBox stores a String, however, so you need to convert that to an Integer first.

A common way to do this is via the [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) function:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    ' Calls independent Sub procedures to display a grade.
    Dim pts As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtPoints.Text, pts) Then
        If radHis101.Checked Then
            lblGrade.Text = GetGrade101(pts).ToString()
        Else
            lblGrade.Text = GetGrade102(pts).ToString()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Points!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that was a big help. It definitely makes more sense now. Now the lblgrade.text = GetGrade102(intPoints) & lblgrade.text = GetGrade101 has a red underline

Comment: Do you have a Label called `lblGrade` on your Form?  That's what it is expecting.  If you already do (double check that .Name property!), then what does the IDE say when you hover over the squiggles?

Comment: Yes I do. When I hove over it says Option Strict On disallows Implicit conversions from integer to String

Comment: Gotcha...add `.ToString()` to the end of your function calls.  I'll edit the code above.

Comment: That helped to get the text in points text box to display in the lblgrade. Which makes it seem as though its not performing the getgrade functon. Its not converting the pointstext to a letter grade

Comment: Actually your code worked. Its displaying the grades. Thank you very very much for your help

Comment: Earl, feel free to Accept a response and/or upvote any answers here that were helpful.